# How do I access the faces of the Subsurf modifier?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Changing the cube into a subdivision surface thingy is what I need to do for the model I am making. However when I try to use edit mode, graphing and faces on the subdivided cube it doesn't register the faces of the subdivision object and instead uses the old cube surface Like below

[image]

Is there a shortcut or something to fix this or do I need to turn on a setting or what? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to hit *Apply* in the modifier settings in order to get faces of the subdivided cube editable in Edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I dont really get your question but i think , you eant your surface to look subdivided without applying the modifier. Just click that triangle thing in the subsurf modifier. And i should do the job. It isnt same as applying the modifier and working with the subdivided mesh tho